# How to concatenate string in _bstr_t and wchar_t?

Tags: c++11, concatenation, wchar-t, bstr-t

I have `_bstr_t` string and I have `wchar_t` and one `unsigned int` variables which I want to put to the string...

```
_bstr_t strCnn("Driver={SQL Server};Server=some_host,some_port;Database=some_db;User ID=some_user;Password=some_psw;");

wchar_t *host,
unsigned int port,
wchar_t *db_name,
wchar_t *user,
wchar_t *password,
```

These 5 variables I pass to the function which does connection. Can you please guide me how to insert them to connection string.

I tried this way:

```
    wstring ws(host);
    string host_str(ws.begin(), ws.end());
    wstring ws_db(db_name);
    string db_str(ws_db.begin(), ws_db.end());
    wstring ws_user(user);
    string user_str(ws_user.begin(), ws_user.end());
    wstring ws_psw(password);
    string psw_str(ws_psw.begin(), ws_psw.end());

    std::string port_str = std::to_string(port);
    _bstr_t strCnn("Driver={SQL Server};Server="+host_str+","+port_str+";Database="+db_str+";User ID="+user_str+";Password="+psw_str+";");
```

But it says:

```
Error E0289 no instance of constructor "_bstr_t::_bstr_t" matches the argument list 
Error C2664 '_bstr_t::_bstr_t(const _bstr_t &) throw()': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'const char *'
```

Comment: Actually as I understand this is wchar_t* type string. How do I convert/concatenate everything to wchar_t?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way would be to use `std::wstringstream`.

Your code could then look something like:

```
    std::wstringstream ws;
    ws << "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" << host << "," << port << ";Database=" << db << ";User ID=" << user << ";Password=" << pswr <<";";
    _bstr_t strCnn(ws.str().c_str());
```

The constructor of `_bstr_t` takes a `const wchar_t*` so no need to do any intermediary conversions.

Comment: std::wstringstream ws;
it says 'incomplete type is not allowed'.

Comment: You need to include the header for `std::wstringstream` - `#include <sstream>`.

Answer (score 1):

When you construct the string to pass to `strCnn`, it is a `std::string` object.  `_bstr_t` does not have a constructor that takes a `string`, but does have one that takes `const char *` (which is what the error message is telling you.

The simple fix is to construct your string and save that in a local variable, then pass that string (converted to a `const char *`) to the `_bstr_t` constructor.

```
std::string port_str = std::to_string(port);
std::string connection = "Driver={SQL Server};Server="+host_str+","+port_str+";Database="+db_str+";User ID="+user_str+";Password="+psw_str+";";
_bstr_t strCnn(connection.c_str());
```

This may not be the optimal way to construct a string (`std::stringstream` may be better).

Since your original parameter strings are wide characters, you can construct the connection string with wide characters (and `std::wstring`).